# Python - bulk set up pycurl options from dictionary

Tags: python, pycurl

Please tell me how to bulk set up pycurl options from dictionary.

Example:

```
options = {
    'WRITEFUNCTION': buffer.write,
    'FOLLOWLOCATION': True,
    'HEADER': True,
    'VERBOSE': False,
    }
options2 = {
    'COOKIEFILE': cookie_file,
    'COOKIEJAR': cookie_file,
    }
options.update(options2)
```

and i need something like that:

```
for opt, val in options.items():
    curl.setopt(pycurl.opt, val)
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Python's [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) method. The start would be the same as yours and then

```
for opt, val in options.items():
    curl.setopt(getattr(curl,opt), val)
```